# 227 subtypes of Mapped class causes slow Entity framework database context initialisation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, orm

I have a class Country, with 227 subtypes (one for each Country).
Legacy restrictions prevent me from easily changing this.

I've double checked that in fact the high number of subtypes is causing EF to have a super slow initialisation, on the first call, the first time the DbContext is accessed it takes about 2 minutes!!

Is there any way I can maintain this high number of subtypes in Entity framework and avoid this slow spin up ??

The hang can occur by doing a simple call to Db.Users.Find(1); (for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's hurting you is the initial ***View Generation*** that ***Entity Framework*** goes through during a cold query (a query against Entities that don't have Views mapped. These Models are the mapping from Entities to Tables that makes EF so efficient afterward:

> The process of computing these views based on the specification of the
>   mapping is what we call view generation. View generation can either
>   take place dynamically when a model is loaded, or at build time, by
>   using "pre-generated views"; the latter are serialized in the form of
>   Entity SQL statements to a C# or VB file.

**Pre-Generated Views** are designed with ***EF*** tools within ***VS*** and built at compile time rather than at run-time.

> You can also consider using the Entity Framework Power Tools to
>   generate views of EDMX and Code First models by right-clicking the
>   model class file and using the Entity Framework menu to select
>   “Generate Views”. The Entity Framework Power Tools work only on
>   DbContext-derived contexts and can be found at
>   http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d.
>
> For more information on how to use pre-generated views on Entity
>   Framework 6 visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469601.

### Check this [Reference on Entity Framework View Generation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx)

Everything you need to know about pre-generating views, applying them, and even moving them to their own assembly (so that View Generation builds are independent of Application release builds.

Answer (score 0):

when you create the first instance of Context ,
EF validate  DB Schema , 
if the model has no changes , you can skip this step by static constractor :

```
static ctor
{
Database.SetInitializer<BillingContext>(null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, hmm that doesn't seem to have helped.